# Can we do better than looking at an 7-day average of new Coronavirus infections?

Tags: forecasting

If we look at the 7 or 14 day average of new infections, we are always lagging behind. I was wondering: can we do better? In essence, the issue with a normal 7-day average is that it gives equal weight to the values for all 7 days, when the last day is actually a much better predictor for the future, than the first day.

Let's model the daily new infections as a function f, where $f(n)$ is the new infections occurring on day n. We define it as $f(n) = f(n-1) r(n)$. The value $r(n)$ is the growth rate on day n. It is defined as $r(n) = r(n-1) + x$, where $x$ is a random real number that follows a normal distribution. In other words, the daily new infections are computed from the growth rate and the previous day, and the growth rate each day will randomly go down or up compared to the previous day. We can also add some random noise $y$ directly to $f$.

Given the data for the previous days, we can calculate which are the values for the next few days that best fit the model.

I am sure that something along these lines must already exist in statistics. Can someone point me to it?

Comment: If we're looking at data of 1 year ago, the day before the day we want to predict probably is more informative than any of the other 6 days before it. However, if we're talking about current events, the ones in which we usually use the 7-day average, the day before the day we want to predict sometimes is the LESS informative among them all. This happens because it takes time for the real data to be assembled. In Brazil, it was estimated that it can take even months for the number to be the right one. Usually, at least a few days or a week or two.

Comment: COVID forecasting is a highly active research area, and yes, there are indeed many, many more sophisticated ways of forecasting it. The proposed duplicate contains links to more resources, along with a lively discussion about how well they work. Be aware that this is the kind of stuff people do their Ph.D. on...